# What do they call the players stacks of chips? Like his bank or somethin'

Tags: terminology

This is such a dumb question, I know, but I've looked through several glossaries and have not found the answer. Each player has his pile of chips next to him that he uses for play. What do they call that?

Answer (score 4):

You literally said it in your question :). It's most often referred to as their stack. Many will also just simply refer to them as their chips either.

Answer (score 0):

Another one is literally in your question - **PILE**  because that's what it is.

> Scot make a pile playing poker.